# detecting location change in angular if route do not used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple menu on the page, who looks like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#/home">home</a></li>
<li><a href="#/work">work</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when I pressing to the link my path change and I want to bind some data retrieval logic for that moment.

So my question is how I could track that location was changed???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `$routeChangeStart` event will fire in this case, but you can watch `$location` path for changes

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $location.path();
}, function() {
    //callback
});
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Will accept your answer as soon as it will be possible.